# Blockquotes are not visually distinguished on the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, blockquote

I realize that the blockquote styling on a regular browser is kind of subtle to begin with, but the Android app doesn't currently render blockquotes in a way that makes them visually identifiable at all. They just look like normal text, although they do seem to have a *very* slight amount of extra padding on the left side. Code blocks render as I would expect.

In the below screenshot, the circled paragraph is a quote (see the original [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/9643/981)):

[image]

Comment: +1 for freehand circle. (and valid concern, but that's irrelevant)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, we'll get it fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. It's fixed and will go out in the next update of the app. Currently blockquotes look the same as code blocks, which might change in the future but it's better than not signifying them at all.